# Python. Выполнение 1 команды раз в календарный день или раз в 24 часа

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, циклы, while, sleep

Необходимо реализовать функцию для моего проекта (бот вк): есть команда, которая доступна раз в день, ее можно ограничить командой `time.sleep()`, но это заставляет спать весь код. Мне же необходимо, чтобы программа уведомляла пользователя о том, что команда недоступна в ближайшее время и сама программа не завершалась.

```
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen(): #прослушка событий ВК
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW: #ловит события в сообщениях
            msg_text = event.text.lower() #текст сообщения
            if event.from_chat: #ловит события в беседах
                chat_id = event.chat_id
                    if msg_text == 'task a':
                        *если команда в откате*:
                            send_message('Вы уже использовали эту команду. Повторите через *оставшееся время/завтра*')
                        *если команда не в откате*:
                            task_a()
                            time.sleep(86400) #24 часа
```

`time.sleep()` заставляет весь цикл спать, хотя в нем еще много других команд, которые прекратят работу. Привязка команды к календарному дню тоже рассматривается, но не знаю, как грамотно реализовать.

Comment: можете посмотреть в сторону этой библиотеки [shedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) и добавить эту функции в отдельный поток

Comment: Полезная библиотека, взял на вооружение, благодарю. Но вопрос по поводу ответа пользователю о неготовности выполнения команды остается открытым

Comment: можете просто при получении ответа сравнивать время и выводить ответ пользователю что то вроде `if datetime.strptime("17:00:00", "%H:%M:%S").time() datetime.datetime.now().time() < datetime.strptime("19:00:00", "%H:%M:%S").time(): print(1)`